# Keep getting NaN in Google Script while adding numbers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a gui designed using UI Services in Google Apps Script. It has two text boxes for entering numbers, named "number1" and "number2". When ever I run the app and enter two number in the field and click the button the answer textbox says `NaN`, instead of showing the answer I expect. Why?

Here's some of the code, you can also [find it here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwl_E4VfJpBSvSqQ_duAOkiyxQAJ3CAz3kCx-TOENxE/dev).:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.add(app.loadComponent("calcgui"));
  return app;
}

function buttonClicked(userInput) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var a = userInput.parameter.number1;
  var b = userInput.parameter.number2;
  var answer = parseInt(a, 10) + parseInt(b, 10);
  app.getElementById('answer').setText(answer);
  return app;
}
```

Comment: There is no question in your text. Where does the error appear. It might helpfull if we could the the HTML.

Comment: Oh sorry, when ever i run the app in google script and enter two number in the field and click the button the answer textbox says NaN, I google about that and couldnt find an answer why it is doing that and not adding the two numbers.

Comment: [link]https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwl_E4VfJpBSvSqQ_duAOkiyxQAJ3CAz3kCx-TOENxE/dev   thats the link to it published maybe that can help.

Comment: Can you make that script publicly accessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for sharing

I solved the issue on your script.
When using the GUI builder, you need to add a callbackElement to the server handler. This can be done in the GUI interface as shown in the first image (see properties of the + button, down the list, near the function name there is a little + where you can add the relevant widget ID or its parent.
In this case I choosed the flowPanel that contains all widgets.

but in any case I'd suggest you switch to UiApp  for these kind of app since the GUI builder will not be available soon.

[image]  [image]